# Intervals over which a sequence of functions converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis

I have some questions about the problem I'm working on:

> Find all intervals on which the sequence $f_n(x)=\frac{x^{2n}}{n+x^{2n}}$, $n \geq 1$, converges uniformly.

I am not sure if what I have is correct. I am studying for a real analysis final so this is practice to try and fully understand the concepts. The definition of uniform convergence I am using is

> Given $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a sequence of functions $(f_k)$ in $C(S,\mathbb{R}^m)$, $(f_k)$ converges uniformly to $f$ if and only if $f_k - f \in C_b (S,\mathbb{R}^m)$ for all $k$ sufficiently large and
>
> $$\lim_{k \to \infty} ||f_k - f||_{\infty} = 0.$$

Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ yields

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x) = 0$$

for $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x) = 1$$

for $|x|>1$. Now, what are my next steps? Do I use my definition over these intervals? Also, how would I go about finding $\sup_{x \in [a,b]}|f_n (x)|$? That is, how would I find

$$||f_n(x)||_{\infty}$$

I am really looking for intuition on solving these types of problems. Any help in that regard would be greatly appreciated. Sometimes I can find $|| f_k ||_{\infty}$ without a problem because I can maximize the function in terms of $x$ by first derivative test, and then plug this value into the function and let $k \to \infty$ to get

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} ||f_k||_{\infty}.$$

It seems that the steps involved in checking for the uniform convergence of a sequence of functions $f_n (x)$ are:

1. Find $f$ by taking $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n (x)$
2. Find the supremum of $f_n - f$, which in many cases ends up being $f_n - 0$, so find the supremum of $f_n$. Do this by finding the value for $x$ that maximizes the function.
3. Plug this value into the function.
4. Take the limit.

It seems to be finding the supremum that stumps me. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

We have the uniform convergence in $[0,1]$ since:
$$\frac{x^{2n}}{n+x^{2n}}\leq \frac{1}{n}\quad\forall x\in[0,1]$$

In the interval $(1,+\infty)$ we have not the uniform convergence (*and the same result in $(-\infty,-1)$ since the function is even*), in fact:

Let $x_n=1+\frac{1}{n}$ then $$|\frac{x_n^{2n}}{n+x_n^{2n}}-1|\sim_\infty |\frac{e^2}{n+e^2}-1|\not \to 0$$

**Added** By a simple derivation we can see that the function $x\mapsto 1-\frac{x^{2n}}{n+x^{2n}}$ is decreasing on every interval $[a,+\infty)$ where $a>1$ then we have
$$|1-\frac{x^{2n}}{n+x^{2n}}|\leq 1-\frac{a^{2n}}{n+a^{2n}}=\frac{n}{n+a^{2n}}\to0$$
hence we have the uniform convergence on every interval on the form $[a,+\infty)$ where $a>1$.

Comment: $+^{+_{+^{+}}}$ for making the problem easier step by step.