# Find the interval where $f_k(x)$ is uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I've been thinking this problem for so long it doesn't make sense to me now.
I've been checking the other questions asked here on MSE, about it, (like these: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358526/intervals-over-which-a-sequence-of-functions-converges-uniformly), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414432/uniform-convergence-of-functions-and-intervals), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370023/how-to-prove-a-sequence-of-a-function-converges-uniformly), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374335/suppose-f-nx-xn-x2n-x-in-0-1-dose-the-sequence-of-functions,)).

I have to show where this sequence converges uniformly: $$f_k(x):=\frac {x^3+kx}{kx^2+1}$$ with $f_k:[0,\infty)\to \Bbb R$

So far I've found the pointwise convergence, and is $f(x)=\frac 1x$.

If we look at the plot, and also by the fact that its limit is $1/x$, is clear that if $x\in [-1,1]$ the function goes crazy high as $k\to \infty$, so maybe the sequence is not uniformly convergent there, but for $|x|>1$ it approaches zero, so my *gut* tells me that is uniformly convergent there, I don't know if I'm interpreting the plot correctly, my *gut* hurts :( .

Now if I want to apply the techniques of the other questions, the difficulties that I find are that $f$ is not a constant nor a function that depends only of $k$ and it doesn't have a global max, so I'm stuck on how to procede.

Also I've noticed that $f_k(\frac 1k)\to 1$ and $f_k(k)\to \infty$, when $k\to\infty$, but this confuses me, would it mean that if $\alpha>0$, then $f_k$ doesn't converge in $[0,\alpha]$? if so, what does this $f_k(k)\to \infty$ means?

Here's the plot of some points: $k=1, k=2, k=4, k=20, k=100$  [image: plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careful. The $f_k$ converge pointwise to $x^{-1}$ if $x\neq 0$, but to $0$ if $x=0$. This tells you immediately that you'll have problems near the origin! On the other hand, your $f_k$ are unbounded on $[a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,a]$ for any $a$. Can you show that on any *bounded* interval that is bounded away from the origin convergence is uniform? Can you show it cannot be uniform on any interval containing the origin or any unbounded interval?

Comment: Any bounded interval? even those where the sequence increases really high, like $(0,\alpha)$?

Comment: @AnaGalois "...bounded away from the origin" means that the interval is of the form $(a,b)$ or $[a,b]$ with either $a>0$ or $b<0$.

Comment: oh! sorry!!! ok, yeah I think I got it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that uniform convergence preserves continuity.